# I need to know how to change the text color in my contact form

Tags: forms, contacts

I have a contact form and I have it set exactly the way I like it, however the text is white, so when you type in it you cant see it. When you highlight it it is there so it is working, however people can't see what they are typing. I have it hosted here www.trutattoo.amdesigns.studio.com

```
                 and this is my CSS

                          form label,

              form .label {
          display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
          }

       input,
       textarea {
     margin-top: 20px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 800;
   font-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    outline: none;
     -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s;
     -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s;
     -o-transition: border-color 0.2s;
     transition: border-color 0.2s;
      }

   input[type="text"],
   textarea {
   padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;


     }

      input[type="text"]:focus,
     textarea:focus {
       border-color: #161616;
       }

           input[type="checkbox"] {
          display: none;
              }

        textarea {
         margin-top: 20px;
       height: 200px;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

font-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;

## 000000 to any color you want.

Example change to #ff0000 is you want RED.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried that, it seems obvious haha, but that didn't work :/